# What to do with a user who's offering bad advice, and why are comments being deleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, voting, voting-fraud

It started this morning, with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446501/accent-issues-with-json-encode-on-an-object). Yet another PHP *"something's wrong with my string encoding, `json_encode` produces weird characters"* question. I closed it as duplicate of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745662/reference-why-are-my-special-unicode-characters-encoded-weird-using-json-enco) which explains the whole non-issue. User [haunts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446900/476) me complaining about abuse (now deleted). User pouts in the comments to his question (now deleted). User deletes his question entirely.

Now he's back with a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454083/how-can-i-keep-accented-words-after-a-json-encode); same topic, but apparently he has understood the (non-)issue and wants to offer a solution to it nonetheless. Fine, the new question is well written, on topic, not duplicated (as far as I know) and he's offering a self-coded "solution" as answer. Great. Except, the solution is wrong. It breaks easily.
I try to point that out in a comment. Shortly after the comment vanishes. I post it again. Comment vanishes again. Quite apparently the user is unhappy with me and knows of the flag button, and someone is obliging.

So now we have this pretty highly rated question standing there with a pretty highly rated answer which provides a solution which you just know will break someone's production code half a year down the line and the user doesn't want to hear of it. What do we do?

Comment: Time to keep your distance.  Downvote bad answers, no comments necessary.

Comment: @Hans Sure, but having that code stand there which I'm sure people will find in the future which contains a bug apparently nobody else is seeing... that's not what SO is for... My single downvote alone doesn't work...

Comment: @HansPassant: Doesn't that break our "We want quality content"-mantra?

Comment: @HansPassant The problem is that bad answers with downvotes and no comment explaining how they're broken are far more likely to get pity upvotes.  As much as I wish your suggestion actually worked, in practice, it doesn't.

Comment: Could you post the comment that's being deleted here?  Perhaps you worded it in an unconstructive manor, and we can help you make your point more constructively.

Comment: What about adding another answer that explains not only how to do it correctly, but points out flaws in other ways? If this question has been answered before you could also flag/close as duplicate.

Comment: @Servy I was constructive as hell! ;) Pretty much: *"The problem with this code is that it will break given the wrong input, e.g. "\u": http://3v4l.org/sXoYg"* - No more, no less. I'm not angry at that guy and have no reason to be unconstructive.

Comment: if someone is blindly copying online solution straight into production code solely because, "oh it has that funny green accept mark and upteen thousands votes" (no analysis? no review? no testing?), I'd say they have much bigger problems than that

Comment: @PlasmaHH I can't/don't want to provide a complete answer, because it either means a lot of code which I don't have time to write, a link to a library or explaining why it's a non-issue (which he knows and has said so in the question itself).

Comment: @gnat Okay, but why should tons of people find this question, see that it appears to be a good solution, only to find out after a fair bit of testing that it's not actually valid?  And even if they make a good faith effort to test it, not everyone understand character encoding well enough to know how to find the cases not properly covered.  Having a comment explain that an answer is broken, with a test case that breaks it, saves all of those users the time/effort/grief of finding out that it's broken themselves.

Comment: What was the *exact content* of the comment? Some keywords, when used in a flagged comment, can cause the comment to be insta-deleted on the first flag.

Comment: @deceze: Either this is a pet peeve of you and bothers you so much that you don't want others to step into the trap, so you have to put some effort in. I don't know the correct solution so I can't say how much it is to write the correct answer, but if its not worth that effort for you, you should really do what hans said and step away; this battle may be lost (unless someone else steps away), but the war isn't over, and in the time you get angry about this, you could probably do dozen of more good deeds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters More or less exact comment posted above. My memory isn't that fantastic that I could reproduce it 100% verbatim, but this is pretty much it.

Comment: @gnat: If we don't expect high upvoted and accepted answers code to at least work, what is this babbling about quality on this site then? You can extend that reasoning onto non-code answers too, meaning that in total for everything you should do your own research and ignore SO.

Comment: @deceze: ah, I had missed that comment. I don't see anything obvious about it that would make it flag-worthy, so it was either flagged by multiple users or a moderator indeed removed it based on flagging.

Comment: @PlasmaHH This really is less about this particular battle (although it'd be nice if it was resolved), it's more about having found a situation in which someone uses the system for his own pettiness, promotes bad knowledge and actually for some weird reason gets away with it. What to do in this case?

Comment: @deceze The discussion won't really move forward until a mod steps in and explains what happened, posting the text of the comment, along with what triggered deletion (either mod deletion, 6 spam/offensive flags, or your use of a blacklisted keyword + one flag).

Comment: Heh, they were all insta-deleted by having three obsolete flags. Although, I thought it was supposed to take six? Guess not. One of those times I wish we could see the *user* who cast the comment flags.

Comment: @animuson That's pretty darn weird.

Comment: @animuson: So this user has a posse of friends or sock puppets to flag comments then? Anything odd with the voting on those posts that might correlate?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks like it. I'll have to get a dev to look at it because there's simply not enough history on these accounts to show anything meaningful to me. I have a suspicion the high vote counts are not valid, though.

Comment: @Servy the way how you phrase the concern, makes a solid reason to worry (_tons of readers need much testing only to find out that content rated as good is indeed garbage_). As opposed to current wording, which reads _some lame sucker dumps it straight from the answer to prod_

Comment: @PlasmaHH ^^^ see above, I only pointed that current wording explaining the concern is slippery

Comment: Isn't the new question still a duplicate?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not so sure about that. The original question/answer is about the the fact that this is by design and that there is no need to do anything special and that the correct way to avoid this is supported by any non-eold language version. The new question is about how to "fix" the design in older versions of the language.

Comment: Looks like he gave up.

Comment: It kinda feels like bullying tho. He seemed to have some PHP proficiency.

Comment: @animuson: Still don't understand why SE goes through the trouble to hide comment flag information from us. What does that *achieve*?

Comment: @BoltClock - Yeah, truth. I think it's just  the whole "2nd-class-citizen" stamp on comments. But it doesn't add up to treat comments as 2nd-class , but then give "2nd-class" users abilities to flag & effectively delete them

Comment: Isn't the obsolete flag kind of broken if people can abuse it to remove unwanted (not-actually-obsolete) comments without moderator intervention?

Comment: @Coffee I'm not going to dispute that the user apparently had a bad experience. But SO is for providing accurate technical information, not for stroking personal egos. Taking criticism is part of the routine.

Comment: And so apparently the answer what to do is to bring it up on meta. Does anyone think there'll be any policy changes for flags or such?

Comment: In my experience going to the (PHP) chat and posting a link with a proper explanation will trigger a lot of comments and downvotes. If you are in the right, the community will help you.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As has been indicated in the comments, not all removed comments are done so by moderators. If a comment contains specific words (obscenities, certain commonly abused phrases, etc.), a single "rude or offensive" flag can remove those immediately. Also, if enough members of the community get together to flag a comment, it can also be removed automatically.

In this case, your comments were removed by a series of flags cast against them. The circumstances around this are incredibly suspicious, and these comments should not have been removed. This is one of those things that falls into the category of "odd enough for a moderator to look into", so I highly recommend casting an "other" flag on one of the posts and explaining what you see.

Coordinated flags against posts was once considered more of a theoretical exploit than a practical one, but we've had a small handful of users attempt this using sock puppets over the last couple of years. We generally don't take kindly to this, and really appreciate when people point it out. I should say that it is still extremely rare, though.

Comment: @SList - It was flagged as not being constructive, and removed by a moderator. Generally, comments telling someone to do a Google search tend to be frowned on by the community and don't really add to a question, so if flagged we usually remove them. They come off as a little rude, and given Stack Overflow's high search ranking they sometimes just cause someone to circle back to here.

Answer (score -20):

I think he got reddit involved to boost the upvote :P

Most likely some fishy stuff happening though.  What were your comments specifically? Why would decent comments be deleted quickly though (seems like a glitch in system).

This is another variant of the old adage - "You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink"

I would say no need to get so invested into preventing someone's bugs down the line. Maybe I'm not a PHP guru, but is the security vulnerability very serious? Maybe all they want is a "good-enough-for-now" answer.

Comment: The comment isn't there for the post author.  It's there for every single other person who comes along and reads the answer, so that they know it won't work and why.  Having one person knowingly use a poor solution is indeed something you can't stop them from doing, but you *can* prevent them from misleading other people into thinking it's an appropriate solution.

Comment: "is the security vulnerability very serious" That's the same attitude that results in the big breaches you hear about on the news... If you have outside-facing code, you want to be *sure* it's watertight.

Comment: Fair enough, I stand corrected

Comment: I certainly like cupcakes with my coffee.

Comment: I would think that the downvotes on this question mostly come from the lax attitude towards correcting security issues and bugs in answers.

Comment: YIKES!!!! excuse me, I need some coffee. This is a beating indeed.

Comment: @Cupcake - True, you're right. Security is paramount these days . Sigh, it's Ok Cupcake. I have tough skin , and I learned my lesson!  ;-)